# Stopping a sound with openSL

Tags: android, opensl

How can I stop a sound which is played in a native app on android using openSL ES ? For example, I want to play a music while the player navigates in the game menu but as soon as he starts a game I need to stop the music. I use bufferqueue to play sound.

Thank you

Comment: I may found a solution, I read in the doc that we can change the state of the player to stopped or paused. Something like that : (*playItf)->SetPlayState(playItf, SL_PLAYSTATE_STOPPED); I'll try to test on my project and give feedback.